# Importing a lot interconnected data with EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

So I have this need to import (currently) about 15k products. Each product has 20 properties, and also information that belong to other tables - for example, the warehouse used for this product. To avoid saving the same information a bunch of times, I've created a Warehouse-table which contains the address, name and id. The name and address are the ones listed on the import I run.

Now there are other linked pieces of data related to the product that may or may not already exist in the database.

The way I currently do this is by checking if the related entries exist as I come by them, and if they do not, I add them to the database using another context and return the id of the newly generated entity. The actual products are added to the "main" context and saved after all have been added. Something like this:

```
using (var context = new MyContext())
{
  foreach (var product in productList)
  {
      CheckWarehouse(product);
      CreateEntityFromProduct(product);
  }
  context.SaveChanges();
}
```

While this does work with the current amount of data to some degree, it still is rather slow, so I'm wondering, what would be a better way to go about this?

Comment: Can you give is the code of 'CheckWarehouse' and 'CreateEntityFromProduct'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linq is not that good with large amount of data. You could do a bulkinsert. Here is a suggestion that will support large amount of data:

```
void Main()
{
    //Your list of objects
    List<MyObject> TheListOfMyObjects=new List<MyObject>();

    var dt=new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("Prop1",typeof(int));
    dt.Columns.Add("Prop2",typeof(string));
    foreach (var TheObject in TheListOfMyObjects)
    {
        dt.Rows.Add(TheObject.Prop1,TheObject.Prop2);
    }
    InsertWithBulk(dt,"YourConnnectionString","MyObject");
}
private void InsertWithBulk(DataTable dt,string connectionString,string tableName)
{
    using (SqlConnection destinationConnection =new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        destinationConnection.Open();
        using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(destinationConnection))
        {
            bulkCopy.DestinationTableName =tableName;

            try
            {
                bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Exception from the bulk copy
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @bobblez : remember to upvote if you think the answer is good. It gives us all warm-fuzzy feelings

Comment: sure, though the answer doesn't cover the "interconnected" -part. But I suppose I'll just do multiple inserts, starting from the table that doesn't have any foreign keys and work my way towards the more dependent ones. One question though, can I use a single SqlBulkCopy-instance for multiple batch inserts to different tables by just changing the DestinationTableName -property, or should I create a new instance each time?